# How to create a new div for each javascript response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to create a new div for each js response?
Message is a JSON containing all the messages sent and received.

this is my JS:

```
$.get("MessageServlet", function (responseJson) {           
$.each(responseJson, function (index, message) {

 //code to create a div for each response

});
  });
```

My div is like:

```
<div id="somediv">
  <li class="clearfix">
     <div class="message-data align-right"> 
 </div>
   <div id ="messagesent" class="message other-message float-right">
      Hello
   </div>
   </li>
  </div>
```

The div should create a message like this
[image]

This was the code I tried:

```
var codeToInsert="<li class="clearfix"><div class="message-data align-right"><span class="message-data-time" >messaggio.timestamp</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="message-data-name" >You</span> <i class="fa fa-circle me"></i></div><div id ="messagesent" class="message other-message float-right">messaggio.body</div></li>";

var addMessage =document.getElementById('somediv');                                       
addMessage.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', codeToInsert);
```

Comment: ...Just iterate over each message like you're doing and use `createElement`? (and you shouldn't use jQuery just to iterate over an array)

Comment: Doesn't seem like you tried to solve the problem first --- you didn't show any code you tried and why it failed

Comment: here is a similar example http://atomicrobotdesign.com/blog/javascript/using-jquery-and-json-to-display-content/

Comment: @zevee well this is my code:var codeToInsert="<li class="clearfix"><div class="message-data align-right"><span class="message-data-time" >messaggio.timestamp</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="message-data-name" >You</span> <i class="fa fa-circle me"></i></div><div id ="messagesent" class="message other-message float-right">messaggio.body</div></li>";
                                        var addMessage = document.getElementById('somediv');
                                        addMessage.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', codeToInsert);

Comment: Don't post big blocks of code in comments, they're unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has one serious flaw. `var codeToInsert="<li class="cl...` does not escape quotations.

That aside, the answer to your question is:

```
$.get("MessageServlet", function (responseJson) {           
    $.each(responseJson, function (index, message) {

        $('#somediv').append(`
            <li class="clearfix">
                <div class="message-data align-right">
                    <span class="message-data-time">
                        ${message.timestamp}
                    </span> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <span class="message-data-name" >
                        You
                    </span>
                    <i class="fa fa-circle me"></i>
                </div>
                <div id ="messagesent" class="message other-message float-right">
                    ${message.body}
                </div>
            </li>
        `);

    });
});
```

Comment: If you want me to explain why it works, or you don't understand any part of it, feel free to ask and I'll link you to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

You can test with this JQuery code using the `prepend`method:

**JQuery:**

```
var messageBody = "Some text",
    codeToInsert = '<li class="clearfix"><div class="message-data align-right"><span class="message-data-time" >messaggio.timestamp</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="message-data-name" >You</span> <i class="fa fa-circle me"></i></div><div id ="messagesent" class="message other-message float-right">'+messageBody+'</div></li>';

var addMessage = $('#somediv');
addMessage.prepend(codeToInsert);
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `codeToInsert` not defined correctly, `timestamp` and `body` should be added dynamically to `codeToInsert`

```js
var responseJson = [{
  "timestamp": "00001",
  "body": "body 001"
}, {
  "timestamp": "00002",
  "body": "body 002"
}, {
  "timestamp": "00003",
  "body": "body 003"
}];


var codeToInsert = "";
var addMessage = document.getElementById('somediv');

$.each(responseJson, function(index, message) {

  codeToInsert = "<li class='clearfix'><div class='message-data align-right'><span class='message-data-time' >" + message.timestamp + "</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class='message-data-name'>You</span> <i class='fa fa-circle me'></i></div><div id ='messagesent' class='message other-message float-right'>" + message.body + "</div></li>";

  addMessage.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', codeToInsert);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="somediv">
  <li class="clearfix">
    <div class="message-data align-right">
    </div>
    <div id="messagesent" class="message other-message float-right">
      Hello
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```